# ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 413

Tags: python, sockets, streaming, opencv

i'm trying to send a stream from my webcam to client that also on my computer, and i can't solve it:

the error(in the client):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r0504\Desktop\client.py", line 13, in <module>
    frame = np.ndarray(socket.recv(1024).decode())
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 413
```

server:

```
import cv2
import socket
IP = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 5555
socket = socket.socket()
socket.bind((IP,PORT))
socket.listen(1)
(client_socket,client_address) = socket.accept()

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read(1024)
    frame = str(frame).encode()
    client_socket.send(frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

client

```
import cv2
import socket
import numpy as np
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5555
socket = socket.socket()
socket.connect((IP,PORT))
print("connected")

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("test")
while True:
    frame = np.ndarray(socket.recv(1024).decode())
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
```

Also, i can use another way (more affective way) to stream video in python, is using socket is a fast and afficent?

thank you!